# Finding average of values assigned to a field

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro, statistics

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have an attribute table with point data of the amounts of time it takes a vehicle to reach its destination. Each destination is assigned to one of three zones and each response time is categorized as "on-time" or "late". I want to find the average of "on-time" responses per zone. How can I do this?

Fields: Response_Time (in minutes), Outcome ("on-time" or "late"), Zones (3 diff values)

I have tried creating a report, creating a graph, and using summary statistics, but these don't seem to allow expressions nor multiple field inputs. Is python my best bet?

Comment: Summary Statistics can do this using group fields. What precisely have you tried with that tool?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Python approach that generates a dictionary with zones as keys and response times as list values `if` the `Outcome == 'on-time'`. Another dictionary is created to store the zones as keys and the mean response time as values.

```py
import arcpy
import collections

fc = r'C:\path\to\your\geodatabase.gdb\some_featureclass'

# Create an empty dictionary
d = collections.defaultdict(list)

# Populate the dictionary with {zone: [Response_Time,...]}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ("Response_Time", "Outcome", "Zones")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[1] == 'on-time':
            d[row[2]].append(row[0])

# Create a dictionary and calculate mean response time for each zone
mean_d = {}

for k,v in d.items():
    mean_d[k] = sum(v)/float(len(v))

# Show results
print(d)
print(mean_d)
```

---

The first dictionary contains zones and their corresponding list of response times if they are on-time:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [2, 3], 2: [7, 5], 3: [9]})
```

The second dictionary contains the zone and the mean response time:

```
{1: 2.5, 2: 6.0, 3: 9.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a variation using [pandas module and groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```py
import arcpy
import pandas as pd

#Change these five lines to match your data
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\data.gdb'
fc = 'bs_riks_SpatialJoin'
zonefield = 'KKOD'
outcomefield = 'Within'
timefield = 'JOIN_FID'

#Create a dataframe
fieldlist = [zonefield, outcomefield, timefield]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fieldlist), columns=fieldlist)

#Groupby zone and calc mean
df2 = df.loc[df[outcomefield]=='No'].groupby(zonefield)[timefield].mean() #Change No to on-time
```

df2 hold the results:
[image]

Comment: Nice use of Pandas for this. This is the first time I have seen a direct conversion of an attribute table to a Panda's dataframe.